# Apache24 how to proxy and return 404 for undefined endpoints

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have two virtual hosts running on a single Tomcat server.  Lets call them a.com and b.com.  Tomcat is configured to support only http on port 8080.  (This is simplified, in real life there are multiple Tomcat instances each running a set of virtual hosts.)

I am fronting the host with Apache24 for the purpose of proxying incoming https requests to backend http.  This emulates a production environment in which https certificates are handled by a corporate firewall, and requests are forwarded to the backend via http with some additional header fields inserted.

So, I have this proxying for restricted (external) users with two-way authentication:

```
https://a.com:443 -> http://a.com:8080
```

I also have this proxying for trusted (internal) users:

```
http://a.com:80 -> http://a.com:8080
http://b.com:80 -> http://b.com:8080
```

The problem is that due to some Apache24 default handling, a request to https://b.com/foo gets routed to http://a.com:8080/foo.  I want to the https to b.com to return a 404!  I know I need some default mappings to kill the b.com request but so far nothing has worked.

The Apache24 details:

```
File httpd-vhosts.conf:
<VirtualHost a.com:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName a.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/tmp"

    ProxyPass / http://a.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://a.com:8080/
    
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost b.com:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName b.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/tmp"

    ProxyPass / http://b.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://b.com:8080/
    
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</VirtualHost>

File httpd-ssl/conf:
<VirtualHost a.com:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    SSLEngine On
    ServerName a.com
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 2
    SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on
    
    #RewriteEngine On
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
    RequestHeader setifempty CUSTOMFIELD "expr=CN=%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}"

    ProxyPass / http://a.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://a.com:8080/
    
    SSLCertificateFile "c:/certs/a.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/certs/a.com.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile "c:/certs/ca.crt"
    
</VirtualHost>
```

I see in the Apache24 logs lines that start like this when I request https://b.com/foo:

```
mod_proxy.c(880): [client 127.0.0.1:57956] AH03461: attempting to match URI path '/foo' against prefix '/' for proxying
mod_proxy.c(997): [client 127.0.0.1:57956] AH03464: URI path '/foo' matches proxy handler 'proxy:http://a.com:8080/foo'
```